# Problem with JQuery cycle on IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with IE8 displaying a black background during the transition of the food images on IE8, mid-way through this page http://bit.ly/mDcm2v

Another more minor problem is that the link hover underlines are appearing two close to the text, only on this browser, is there a way to fix that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because IE8 can only apply 1 style effect on an element at once.

Since the images are transparent PNG, you are already using that effect and you can't apply an opacity as well. When it fades, you disable the transparency and add opacity.

You can use one of these hacks to fix it:  [How to solve/hack fading semi-transparent PNG bug in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204457/how-to-solve-hack-fading-semi-transparent-png-bug-in-ie8)

Answer (score 0):

To Solve PNG `Background-image` `transparent` issue Please check this :

[Transparent PNG animate problem on Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376710/transparent-png-animate-problem-on-internet-explorer/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cleartypeNoBg:true
```

for more information on this solution:

http://www.leveltendesign.com/blog/dustin-currie/show-background-image-jquery-cycle-ie