# JQuery + opacity + ie8 + png24

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, opacity

What do you think about IE? Yes, it's a very cool browser.
There is PNG24 with a transparent area. I have applied the jquery opacity to it like:

```
$(".selector").css("opacity", 0.4);
```

and got the following problem:

[image: IE8 bug]

How can I fix it?

Comment: IE is a _"very cool browser"_?  Hahahahahaha!

Comment: PNG8 is not supposed to have this issue.  Convert your PNG24 to PNG8 if possible, then let jQuery handle the cross-browser opacity issues as it should.

Comment: @genesis:  Obviously it was a joke... that's why I laughed.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use this Same PNG Method Here for IE
Check This Link For the [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376710/transparent-png-animate-problem-on-internet-explorer/7407038#7407038)

Use -ms-filter for IE8

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=images/banner01.png,
 sizingMethod=crop)";
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use this

```
.selector
{
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)"; /* IE8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);  /* IE7 */

}
```

Comment: I thought jQuery's opacity was supposed to automatically handle any cross-browser issues.

Answer (score -1):

all you need is this :  [DD_belatedPNG](https://github.com/plus2/DD_belatedPNG)